# Screenshot desktop, capture words, get coordinates of words and click on them

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract, pyautogui

I want to take a screenshot of my desktop, interpret the characters on my desktop, group words and then get the coordinates of these words so I can click on them.

```
imageName = "images/desktop.png"
image = cv2.imread(imageName)

# Grab image data/characters
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(image)
print(d)

# Transform them into words? (not working yet, getting an error on len(d['level'])
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    print(x, y, w, h)

# Use these coordinates to click certain buttons etc.
pyautogui.click(coordinates)
```

Is possible? And would it also be possible to take a screenshot of only a piece of my screen but still get the correct coordinates?)

My desktop image is being generated like this:

```
def fullScreenShot():
  # Take a full screen shot.
  with mss.mss() as sct:
    screenShot = sct.shot(output="images/desktop.png")
```

Comment: can you show us the input image and the entire source code you are working with.

Comment: I have attached the code of how I am creating my desktop screenshots. I don't think any of the other code is relevant, since it doesn't link to this functionality! Let me know if that helps. I am triggering the `fullScreenshot()` function at a certain moment, and then after that, I want to run the functionality to read that image and understand where words are, so I can click on them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Firstly create a screenshot of your screen with the mss library, store it somewhere accessible.

```
def fullScreenShot():
  with mss.mss() as sct:
    screenShot = sct.shot(output="images/desktop.png")


# Function to read your desktop image, loop through words found and generate coordinates
    def getCoordinatesOfWords():
        imageName = "images/desktop.png"
        image = cv2.imread(imageName)

        # Image Data
        d = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)

        # Number of boxes
        n_boxes = len(d['level'])
        # Loop through words and get coordinates.
        for i in range(n_boxes):
            (left, top, width, height) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
            if d['text'][i] != 0 and len(d['text'][i]) != 0:
                # Create final coordinates of words, dividing by 2 because I am on a mac retina (resolution is 2x), and dividing width/height by 4, to get center of image.
                coordinatesOfWord = (left/2 + width/4, top/2 + height/4)
```